# JavaFx Rectangle Array Collision with a ball object and remove

Tags: arrays, javafx, collision, geometry, rectangles

I'm trying to make a game like brick breaker as known as 'dxBall'
but when it comes to the rectangle and ball collision my codes are not working or most probably i wrote it wrong. I'm creating a rectangle array, thats cool but when it comes to collision between them ball goes through left or right side of the Rectangle bricks also they can't removed from the screen. How can i fix this code?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    final static int Width=800;
    final static int Height=480;
    private double velocity=10;
    double dx=3;
    double dy=3;
    int radius = 10;
    int xx=400;
    int yy=240;

    //Method of Creating Bricks
    static Rectangle createBrick(int x, int y) {
        Rectangle brick = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 20);
        brick.setFill(Color.RED);

        return brick;
    }
    //method for move the bar
    private void moveCircleOnKeyPress(Scene gamescene,Rectangle bar) {
        gamescene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler <KeyEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case RIGHT: bar.setX(bar.getX() + velocity); break;
                    case LEFT:  bar.setX(bar.getX() - velocity); break;
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{




        Group root = new Group();
        VBox layoutMenu= new VBox(10);
        layoutMenu.setPrefWidth(100);
        Label Score = new Label();
        Score.setText("Score: ");
        Score.setLayoutX(720);
        Score.setLayoutY(5);

        //Array of Bricks
        Rectangle b [] = new Rectangle[45];
        int i=0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 30;
        for(i=0, x = 0; x<=750; x=x+53,i=i+1 ){
            b[i] = createBrick(x,y);
            root.getChildren().add(b[i]);
            if(x==742){
                for( x = 0; x<=750; x=x+53,i=i+1 ) {
                    b[i] = createBrick(x,y+21);
                    root.getChildren().add(b[i]);
                    if(x==742){
                        for( x = 0; x<=750; x=x+53,i=i+1 ) {
                            b[i] = createBrick(x,y+42);
                            root.getChildren().add(b[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Declaring scenes
        Scene menu = new Scene(layoutMenu,Width,Height);
        Scene gamescene = new Scene(root,Width,Height);


        //Creating Buttons
        Button playGameButton= new Button("Play Game");
        Button scoresButton = new Button("Scores");
        Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
        Button menuButton = new Button("Menu");

        //Creating Ball
        Circle ball = new Circle(radius,Color.DARKBLUE);
        ball.relocate(xx,yy);


        //Creating Bar
        Rectangle bar = new Rectangle(325,455,150,20);
        bar.setFill(Color.DARKGREEN);


        // Adding items to the layoutMenu and gameMenu and gamescene
        layoutMenu.getChildren().addAll(playGameButton,scoresButton,exitButton);
        root.getChildren().addAll(menuButton,bar,ball,Score);


        //Align buttons and bar
        layoutMenu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        playGameButton.setMinWidth(layoutMenu.getPrefWidth());
        scoresButton.setMinWidth(layoutMenu.getPrefWidth());
        exitButton.setMinWidth(layoutMenu.getPrefWidth());
        menuButton.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

        //Events of buttons
        playGameButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(gamescene));
        menuButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(menu));

        layoutMenu.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2C3539;");
        primaryStage.setTitle("dxBall");
        primaryStage.setScene(menu);

        moveCircleOnKeyPress(gamescene, bar);
        primaryStage.show();

        final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {



            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
                ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx);
                ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy);

                //Collision for walls
                final boolean atRightBorder = ball.getLayoutX() >= (800 - radius);
                final boolean atLeftBorder = ball.getLayoutX() <= (0 + radius);
                final boolean atBottomBorder = ball.getLayoutY() >= (480 - radius);
                final boolean atTopBorder = ball.getLayoutY() <= (0 + radius+30);

                if (atRightBorder || atLeftBorder) {
                    dx *= -1;
                }
                if (atBottomBorder || atTopBorder) {
                    dy *= -1;
                }

                //Collision for brick bar

                if(ball.getBoundsInParent().intersects(bar.getLayoutBounds())){
                    Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(ball, bar);
                    if(intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1){
                        // Collision handling here
                    }
                    dy*=-1;
                }
                //Bar must stay in scene
                final boolean atRight = bar.getX() >= (800 - 150);
                final boolean atLeft = bar.getX() <= (0);

                if(atRight){
                    bar.setX(650);
                }
                else if(atLeft){
                    bar.setX(0);
                }
            }
        }));

        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an intersection code with the bricks in there, i. e. something like this:

```
for( Rectangle brick: b) {

  if( brick == null)
    continue;

  if( ball.getBoundsInParent().intersects(brick.getBoundsInParent())) {
    ...
  }

}
```

By the way, also the bar should be checked against `getBoundsInParent`, not against `getLayoutBounds`.